# Building in 64 bit Windows on VS2008 gives C2632 error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, build, win64

So I am trying to build an 32 bit application in 64.
I am linking to all 64 bit libraries, and I have recompiled everything we used for 64 bit.

I am getting weird errors now.
I have seen some similar errors over the net but nothing useful in those topics.

Any idea what could be wrong that causes this behavior?

warning C4091: 'typedef ' : ignored on left of 'float' when no variable is declared 
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\windef.h
error C2632: 'float' followed by 'double' is illegal
C:\Program Files\MicrosoftSDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\windef.h

warning C4091: 'typedef ' : ignored on left of 'double' when no variable is declared    C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\wtypes.h
Error   44  error C2632: 'double' followed by 'double' is illegal
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\wtypes.h

Warning and error are for the same line.
Clearly its not a problem with wtypes.h and windef.h (and if it was i cant do anything about it)

```
typedef float               FLOAT;

typedef double DOUBLE;
```

Clearly these are fine by itself so it has to be something else.
File in my project that causes this just includes

Any ideas?

Comment: Are FLOAT and DOUBLE defined previously/elsewhere as macros? (Local source, even?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `FLOAT` and `DOUBLE` have been previously `#define`d to `double`. This might be a result of another library, although it seems unlikely to be caused by switching to 64-bit compilation. Try doing

```
#undef FLOAT
#undef DOUBLE
```

Prior to including `windows.h` or `windef.h` or whichever file is directly responsible for the warning.

Comment: it seems that this fixes the issue, but how would i find out what stepped over the definitions?

Comment: If you put something like `#define DOUBLE TESTER` as the very first line in your source file, the compiler should yell at you at the point (most likely include line) where it's redefined to `double`.

Comment: You could also use trial and error (comment out #includes) or have a look at the preprocessor output (cl /E). Mark B's suggestion is probably your best bet though.